# Php Image merge from multiple images

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I want to make a image from multiple image.In my image list have maximum 6 image.i want to add all image side by side.as example

---

```
1st image          |      2nd image
```

---

```
3rd image          |      4th image
```

---

```
5th image          |      6th image
```

---

I am writing a code that makes image Vertically.

my code

```
<?php



$numberOfImages = 6;
$x = 940;
$y = 920;
$background = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y*6);


$firstUrl = 'e.jpg';

$secondUrl = 'f.jpg';

$thirdUrl = 'f.jpg';

$fourthUrl = 'e.jpg';

$fiveUrl = 'f.jpg';

$sixUrl = 'f.jpg';

$outputImage = $background;

$first = imagecreatefromjpeg($firstUrl);
$second = imagecreatefromjpeg($secondUrl);
$third = imagecreatefromjpeg($thirdUrl);



imagecopymerge($outputImage,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,100);
imagecopymerge($outputImage,$second,0,$y,0,0, $x, $y,100);
imagecopymerge($outputImage,$third,0,$y*2,0,0, $x, $y,100);

imagejpeg($outputImage, APPLICATION_PATH .'test.jpg');

imagedestroy($outputImage);




?>
```

But i want to placed image dynamically cause image item could be 4 or 5 or 6 or 1 or 2 or 3

But how?

Comment: Maybe this answer helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121488/php-gd-merge-multiple-images-in-tiled-layout

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Merge two images in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858489/merge-two-images-in-php)

Adapt that function to either put two images side by side (taking two parameters, each images) and also adapt it to put three images vertically (as it starts with two, you're just adding a third).  This second adaptation would take three parameters of the three images to join.

Then call the functions, nesting one in the other, such as:

```
join3(join2($firstURL, $secondURL), 
      join2($thirdURL, $fourthURL), 
      join2($fifthURL, $sixthURL));
```

and you can set your URL parameters to whatever you want to dynamically call the function.